# How to remove dynamic string from url with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just finished my Wordpress website migration and I found that all my posts ids
 Got changed after the migration what is bad for my SEO because I use the IDs on the
 URLs.

Example of old URL:
    http://www.example.com/news/category/postname-ID.html

Example of new URL:
    http://www.example.com/news/category/postname.html

As you can see I’m not using the IDs anymore on the URLs since it’s not the same.

So I would like to know how to use htaccess to rewrite URLs from Example 1 to Example 2

NB: The Id is not the same it dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give the following rules a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(news/category/.*)\-\d+(\.html) $1$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

assuming that the `ID`s are numeric. This would also fail, if, for eg. your postname is something like: `see-this-post-number-13.html` or `This-is-year-2015.html`